# Plotting just the time from a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Currently I've got a dataframe `on_times` which has got a `DatetimeIndex`. I'd like to plot the frequency of certain events in the dataframe using seaborn's swarmplot without regards to the date part of the index. What I'd thought would work was something like this:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

on_times = pd.read_csv("fridge_freezer_on.csv", parse_dates = ["local_updated"] 
                        index_col = "local_updated")

on_times["Day"] = on_times.index.strftime("%a")
on_times["Time"] = on_times.index.time

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sns.swarmplot(data = on_times, x = "Time", y = "Day", hue = "id")
```

While this code will produce a plot, it seems to be treating the `Time` column as a string, instead of a time. None of the time are in order on the x axis, unlike if I'm plotting a `datetime` column. I'm curious what changes I need to make in order for the x-axis to be the time from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 and to plot the points corresponding to those times.

Comment: What about data example?

Comment: `on_times.index.time` results in a `datetime.time` object, however swarmplots are categorical, which means every time will be on the x-axis. `str(datetime.time(0, 10)) → '00:10:00'`. You can try `on_times = on_times.sort_values(['day', 'time'], ascending=True)` prior to plotting.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working but needed to hack a solution together using a dummy date so that the `Time` column was still a `datetime` because otherwise it wouldn't get treated as a time series and is instead treated as a categorical variable where every different `time` value is a different category. Then when plotting it's necessary to format the axis to ignore the date portion of the `Time` column.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

on_times = pd.read_csv("fridge_freezer_on.csv", parse_dates = ["local_updated"] 
                       index_col = "local_updated")

on_times["Day"] = on_times.index.strftime("%a")
time = on_times.index.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
dummy_date = "2023-08-01"
on_times["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(dummy_date + ' ' + time)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.swarmplot(data = on_times, x = "Time", y = "Day", hue = "id")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
```

The code above produces the expected output with the x-axis showing the time from midnight one day to midnight the next.